# iOS Property List Not Loading All Data

Tags: ios, property-list

My friend and I are working on a puzzle game that loads its level data from a Property List. Our issue seems to be that for some of the dictionary keys, it loads the data properly, but for others it does not. Also, making a change to the property list tends to cause it to not load properly as well.

My guess is that is has something to do with the devices caching property list data, but I'm not sure. We've tried almost everything we and the Internet can think of, to no avail. (i.e. deleting the application off of both the simulator and the physical device between property list changes, etc.)

I'm happy to share relevant code that anybody thinks could help lead to the answer, I'm just not sure what would be relevant. So let me know what you need.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the property list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>level99</key>
    <dict>
        <key>xDimension</key>
        <integer>19</integer>
        <key>yDimension</key>
        <integer>7</integer>
        <key>levelArray</key>
        <array>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>E</string>
            <string>E</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>level10</key>
    <dict>
        <key>xDimension</key>
        <integer>5</integer>
        <key>yDimension</key>
        <integer>8</integer>
        <key>didBeat</key>
        <false/>
        <key>levelArray</key>
        <array>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>level0</key>
    <dict>
        <key>yDimension</key>
        <integer>5</integer>
        <key>xDimension</key>
        <integer>5</integer>
        <key>didBeat</key>
        <false/>
        <key>levelArray</key>
        <array>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>level1</key>
    <dict>
        <key>xDimension</key>
        <integer>5</integer>
        <key>yDimension</key>
        <integer>8</integer>
        <key>didBeat</key>
        <false/>
        <key>levelArray</key>
        <array>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>B</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>level2</key>
    <dict>
        <key>xDimension</key>
        <integer>5</integer>
        <key>yDimension</key>
        <integer>8</integer>
        <key>didBeat</key>
        <false/>
        <key>levelArray</key>
        <array>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>level3</key>
    <dict>
        <key>xDimension</key>
        <integer>5</integer>
        <key>yDimension</key>
        <integer>8</integer>
        <key>didBeat</key>
        <false/>
        <key>levelArray</key>
        <array>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>level4</key>
    <dict>
        <key>xDimension</key>
        <integer>5</integer>
        <key>yDimension</key>
        <integer>8</integer>
        <key>didBeat</key>
        <false/>
        <key>levelArray</key>
        <array>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>level5</key>
    <dict>
        <key>xDimension</key>
        <integer>5</integer>
        <key>yDimension</key>
        <integer>8</integer>
        <key>didBeat</key>
        <false/>
        <key>levelArray</key>
        <array>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>level6</key>
    <dict>
        <key>xDimension</key>
        <integer>5</integer>
        <key>yDimension</key>
        <integer>8</integer>
        <key>didBeat</key>
        <false/>
        <key>levelArray</key>
        <array>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>level7</key>
    <dict>
        <key>xDimension</key>
        <integer>5</integer>
        <key>yDimension</key>
        <integer>8</integer>
        <key>didBeat</key>
        <false/>
        <key>levelArray</key>
        <array>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>level9</key>
    <dict>
        <key>levelArray</key>
        <array>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>R</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>B</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>*</string>
            <string>Y</string>
            <string>*</string>
        </array>
        <key>xDimension</key>
        <integer>5</integer>
        <key>yDimension</key>
        <integer>8</integer>
        <key>didBeat</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>level8</key>
    <dict>
        <key>didBeat</key>
        <false/>
        <key>yDimension</key>
        <integer>8</integer>
        <key>xDimension</key>
        <integer>5</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And here is the code that loads the property list

```
-(NSDictionary *)getLevelDictionaryForLevel:(int)level{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Group1.plist"];
    NSDictionary *plistData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];
    NSDictionary *currentLevelData = [plistData objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"level%i", level]];

    return currentLevelData;
}
```

Comment: Show the plist file and show the code that loads the plist. Show the code that indicates that not all of the data is loaded as expected.

Comment: Try clearing the build folder before running with `command`+`option`+`shift`+`k` (in xcode)

Comment: @rmaddy, we know it is not working properly because of a visual cue, as well as debugging through and seeing the array remaining null.

Comment: @Jugale, thanks for the suggestion! unfortunately, this did not fix our error.

Comment: It's still not clear. What array is `nil`? When? Under what conditions? You need to provide more details.

Comment: @rmaddy, I apologize if I'm not being clear enough. Let me walk you through a short rundown of what is happening. Upon load of a level, the property list is referenced in order to set a level `array`, this is seen in the property list as the array of strings. That array is supposed to get copied into a `dictionary` and then `array` that our level builder sees. The `array` that is `nil` is the `array` that the level builder is supposed to see, after being copied it's like it's not being copied. The weird problem is that it only happens with some of our levels, others work perfectly.

Comment: Show the code where the problem exists and point out a specific level giving you the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @rmaddy and @Jugale for the advice and questions furthering the discussion. I wanted to take a second to respond and say that the error (unfortunately, and probably predictably) had nothing to do with the way the property list data was being referenced.

It was a mistake in the way our code was handling building our grid of tiles, and scaling it.

Again, thanks for all the help!